# How to show these three-regular graphs on 10 vertices are non isomorphic?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

[image]

The number of vertices and edges are same, with each vertex having the same degree and the degree sequence of the graph is also the same. I have even tried finding a bipartite graph in any one of them even that seems to fail.

Question- How to show the three graphs with degree sequence [3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3] are non isomorphic (see figure)?

Comment: @RushabhMehta all of them are non isomorphic !

Comment: To show the graph 1 is not isomorphic, see that there are no 4-cycles in the graph, compared to the other two which do.

Comment: @RushabhMehta can we say that graph 2 does not have a cycle of length 4 for all vertices but graph 3 has a cycle of length 4 for all vertices

Comment: I said that graph 1 doesn't have a cycle of length 4, the other 2 do.

Comment: @Random yes, that's right. In graph 1, there are no vertices in 4-cycles. In graph 2, some, but not all, vertices are in 4-cycles. In graph 3, all vertices are in 4-cycles. This is enough to show no two are isomorphic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Count the number of quadrilaterals and the number of pentagons in each graph. ( 4-cycles and 5-cycles )

You will come up with different numbers which indicate these are not isomorphic graphs.

Comment: Or just quadrilaterals?

Comment: That is true as well.

Answer (score 2):

The first graph is the only one not containing $4$-cycles, so it's not isomorphic to the other two. The second and third graphs are not isomorphic because the third is planar and the second contains a subdivision of $K_{3,3}$.